# angular js : ng-class use

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

i get a data for RestApi and i want create a function to retrieve data from json 
if the defautl == null or the default. value = false . i change the color using ng -class of the component.

```
 1:
commandStateTypes:{
defaut interne:null
defaut liaison:{date: "2016-05-30T01:01:04", value: true, name: "defaut liaison", idComponent: 1}}
component:{id:1 ,idInstallation:1,name:"Commande1"}

2:
commandStateTypes:{
defaut interne:null
defaut liaison:{date: "2016-05-30T01:01:04", value: true, name: "defaut liaison", idComponent: 2}}
component:{id:1 ,idInstallation:1, name:"Commande 2"}

 controller : 
     $scope.status = { state: ['OK', 'KO'] }

  Service.GetComponentsHelpers(function (data)
     {

         $scope.componentsHelper = data;


    },
    function (data)
    {

    });


     $scope.GetStateByComponents = function ()
     {

         angular.forEach($scope.componentsHelper, function (componentsState, key)
         {
             angular.forEach($scope.componentsHelper.commandStateTypes, function(value, key){

             });

         });

     }
     chtml:
     <div class="ajoutComponent">
            <div class="motorsVitesse"  ng-class="{ GetStateByComponents() ? 'mDangerV':'mDefaultV'}" alt="{{status.state[1]}}"> {{status.state[1]}}</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It is hard to understand both what you want and what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: how i can fetch th dictionnary to get state of default

Answer (score -1):

Try this in HTML:

```
ng-class="{'mDangerV': GetStateByComponents(), 'mDefaultV': !GetStateByComponents()}"
```